# Redirect some IP to localhost

Tags: linux, routing

Can I use `route` or some other tool to tell my linux box that it should connect to localhost instead of a given IP (of some other machine on the internet, not on the same subnet)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to configure another loopback address. Assuming you have one loopback already:

```
ifconfig lo:1 inet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx netmask 255.255.255.255 up
```

Note: This will need to be added to a start-up script since each time you reboot, this configuration is lost.

Answer (score 0):

`rinetd` will listen on a IP/port and forward it to an IP/port of your choosing.  It doesn't care about what subnet either IP is in.

I haven't checked `nc` (netcat)'s options too closely but it might be able to do that too.